# Is there a way to show junctions differently in windows explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-explorer, junction

I've started using junctions to remap folders on my Windows XP box.  It's great - I have two drives, so this simplifies my organization.

I would like it if Windows Explorer visually differentiated junctions vs. normal folders.  Ideally an overlay icon (like the little arrow for shortcuts) or a different color (like for compressed files) would be perfect.

Is there any way to do this?  I can always use a separate utility (like junction link magic) to scan for junctions, and I can easily open the command prompt and just "dir" to see junctions.  But I'd really also like to have visual feedback in Explorer itself.  Thanks!

Comment: Someone had said (link below) showing the "Link Target" column in Explorer would show its Junction's destination, I just tried ALL columns (5min ordeal hitting down+space to check) in Win10 & none will show it. I was looking for a native way to show junction points/destinations, I guess I'm stuck with `dir a/:s`
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/ce905f6b-590f-4344-b12e-f87e3db42603/directory-junction-display-destination-in-windows-explorerexe?forum=winservergen

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html). That will use a different icon for junctions and links.

Comment: Ahh, thanks!  This did in fact add an icon to junctions, which is perfect.

Answer (score 4):

Be warned, that deleting a junction from Windows Explorer will in fact **delete the target folder**, therefore I would recommend using some other file manager like Total Commander - it shows junctions with a different icon.

Update: As of Windows 7, deleting the junction won't delete the target folder anymore, so this has apparently been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I've used NTFSLink and found it effective: http://elsdoerfer.name/ntfslink

It also makes the behavior a bit more intuitive particularly vis-a-vis deletions.